# Select case when query not working

Tags: mysql

I am not sure how cases work with mysql, can anyone explain what's wrong with this query?

```
CASE WHEN SELECT COUNT(*) from websites where website_id = 171 and master = 2 > 0
SELECT timestamp from websites where website_id = 171 and master = 2 
ELSE SELECT NOW() as timestamp
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [MySQL Control Flow Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html)

CASE...WHEN needs to have a `THEN` keyword to work.

You probably want:

```
CASE 
    WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) from websites where website_id = 171 and master = 2) > 0
      THEN (SELECT timestamp from websites where website_id = 171 and master = 2) 
    ELSE NOW()
END as timestamp
```

If there are only two possibilities, though, you're better with IF:

```
IF((SELECT count(*) from websites where website_id = 171 and master = 2) > 0,  
   (SELECT timestamp from websites where website_id = 171 and master = 2),  
   NOW()) AS TIMESTAMP
```

Or, you could use IFNULL and skip the count(*)

```
IFNULL((SELECT timestamp from websites where website_id = 171 and master = 2),
   NOW()) AS TIMESTAMP
```

Comment: I'm getting errors on all those 3 queries: `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IFNULL`, the same at `IF(SELECT` and `CASE WHEN` - not sure what I am doing wrong. I'm running these in phpmyadmin

Comment: Wow, I left out a couple of paren's.

Comment: These `select case when (select 1 from dual)>30 THEN 1 else 2 end from dual;`, `select if(1, (SELECT 1 FROM DUAL), now()) FROM DUAL;`, `select ifnull((SELECT 1 FROM DUAL), now()) FROM DUAL;` work on MySQL command line (as do their counterparts (SELECT NULL instead of SELECT 1).

Comment: Weird, it works when passed through php, won't work directly in phpmyadmin. I need it work with php, so it works then! Thank you for your patience cwallenpoole!

Answer (score 1):

I think you could re-write your query like:

```
SELECT COALESCE(timestamp, NOW()) from websites where website_id = 171 and master = 2
```

Comment: A nice and clear way of doing it. (Note that if the table websites contains duplicates for your where clause you will get duplicate results; you may need a `GROUP BY`).

Comment: Does not work if the row does not exist, i want to return NOW() if the row does not exist. Only works on null values.

Answer (score 0):

When using embedding selects to get values, you need to wrap the select in brackets. Also, `CASE` needs to be closed with an `END`.
Try this:

```
CASE
  WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) from websites where website_id = 171 and master = 2) > 0
    THEN (SELECT timestamp from websites where website_id = 171 and master = 2)
  ELSE (SELECT NOW())
END as timestamp
```

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CASE WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) from websites where website_id = 171 and m' at line 1

Comment: This is a case statement. Of course you ca''t execute it. Put in inside a SELECT. The OP only quoted the CASE, so I only answered with a CASE. Note that my answer is identical with the accepted one.